# How to push custom metric to AMP using lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, prometheus, grafana

I am building monitor dashboard. Using AMP, Grafana.
Is the anyway to push metric data as plaintext to AMP using lambda function ?

I'm try using third library like prometheus-client, but can't push metric to remote write AMP.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear: AMP = Amazon Managed Service for Prometheus, so question is how to push metric to Prometheus.

Prometheus doesn't support metrics push in plaintext format. It supports only metrics push in binary format (grpc).

Let's use Python and `requests` lib. It will be simple:

```
# endpoint = "https://aps-workspaces.<region>.amazonaws.com/workspaces/ws-<id>/api/v1/remote_write"
r = requests.post(endpoint, data=metrics, headers=headers)
if r.status_code!=200:
  raise Exception('Prometheus error: ' + r.content.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
else:
  print("DEBUG: Prometheus remote write: OK")
```

You will need compiled [compiled protobufs](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/tree/main/prompb) for Python to create `metrics` - that binary payload, which you will post:

```
# WriteRequest is from https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/prompb/remote.proto
# Sample, Label, TimeSeries from https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/main/prompb/types.proto

timeseries = [
  TimeSeries(
    labels=[Label(name="<label>", value="<value>")], 
    samples=[
      Sample(
          value=<value>,
          timestamp=<timestamp>
      )])]
metrics = WriteRequest(timeseries=timeseries).SerializeToString()
```

AMP requires [Authenticating Requests (AWS Signature Version 4)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html), so you need to generate all required headers for sigv4 + use `snappy` compression for payload:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': content_type,
          'X-Amz-Date': amz_date,
          'Authorization': authorization_header,
          'X-Amz-Security-Token': session_token,
          'Content-Encoding': 'snappy',
          'X-Prometheus-Remote-Write-Version': "0.1.0",
}
```

That's high level. Probably you can find right libs for each step in your favorite language.

I can imagine also using of Opentelemetry here. Use [ADOT](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/lambda) and your Lambda code will send metrics in OTLP format to local ADOT collector and that will export them to AMP.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using [pushgateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/) if I were you. It's not recommended to push metrics directly to Prometheus according to the official [doc](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/remote_write_spec/):

> The remote write protocol is not intended for use by applications to push metrics to Prometheus remote-write-compatible receivers. It is intended that a Prometheus remote-write-compatible sender scrapes instrumented applications or exporters and sends remote write messages to a server.